# Binding Octave Libraries

Tags: octave

I am working with embed octave. While building the library, I encountered this error, can anyone suggest solution for this.

/usr/local/lib/octave/5.1.0/oct/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/PKG_ADD: /usr/local/lib/octave/5.1.0/oct/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/**init_gnuplot**.oct: failed to load: /usr/local/lib/octave/5.1.0/oct/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/**init_gnuplot**.oct: undefined symbol: _ZTI18handle_cdef_object

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Following instructions of https://wiki.octave.org/Building, I have build the lib in the two ways described there (from repos and from release).  I did not encounter this error.  I found that the symbol is defined in ./libinterp/octave-value/.libs/liboctave_value_la-ov-classdef.o:0000000000000000 V _ZTI18handle_cdef_object.  Success.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?